# Selecting cases in one data set according to values occurring in a different dataset

Tags: spss

I have two data sets data1 and data2 which have same variables but different cases. data1 has a variable x that has specific values. I want to capture cases in data2 variable x whose values match the data1 variable x values.
Is there any specific way to that?
I know we can select individual cases with individual values with each dataset but I am not aware of a method to do it across two data sets.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to create a new variable in `data1` that is marked for values of `X` that exist in `data2`, and then you proceed as usual in `data1`:

```
dataset activate data2.
dataset declare xvals.
aggregate out=xvals /break = x/occursInData2=n.

dataset activate data1.
sort cases by X.
match files /file=*/table=xvals/by X.
```

At this point `data1` will contain a new variable `occursInData2` that only has a value in cases where the value of X occurs also in `data2`.